# Visual Studio Code 'helping' doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I really don't know how to explain my problem. My IDE just stopped 'helping' me coding. As an example in the picture below when I used to write 'this.' the IDE should suggest me all my properties/methods. right now as you see nothing happens no matter how long I'm waiting. looks like something messed up over there, I tried to install it again but same result.

[image]

Comment: So you just end up seeing the "Loading..." pop-up indefinitely?

Comment: yes............

Comment: It's saying `loading...`. Maybe it's just taking time to digest all the context to give you Intellisense.

Comment: nothing changes....

Comment: I found this thread, with similar issue to yours. How does your environment stack up with the one described here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1769 ?

Comment: VSCode has its own tag. From the screenshot, it is not clear what is the TypeScript version you use, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions You might use its latest and see if the issue remains.

Comment: I don't work with TypeScript but some language extensions display problems in the log pane. Go to *View/ Output* and see if you can find something relevant in the top right drop-down selector.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update: after installing it again and update it -problem solved.